# Enumerating the items under a selected group header in Outlook 2007 with VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

The ActiveExplorer.Selection returns a count of 0 if the selection is a group header. Does anyone know if it's possible to enumerate the items under that group header using VBA or an add-in?

Comment: Did you actually got this solved?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that's a new feature for Outlook 2010. The group header is not exposed to code in any previous version.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about 2007 but in 2010 this is handled by calling the GetSelection method on the Selection object and pass the OlSelectionContents.olConversationHeaders to the method. This gives a collection of conversationheaders which can then be enumerated.